# Open all files listed in current buffer

Tags: buffers, command

I have a file/buffer that contains multiple file names with line numbers. Example:

```markdown
Declaration of x
    fileA.h +3

Usage of x
    fileB.c +10
```

I can open a file with the cursor in the given line number with `gF`. I can list all file names with `:g/ +\d/`. But how can I open all files listed in this buffer?

I have tried `:g/ +\d/normal gF`. But this opens only `fileA.h`, not `fileB.c`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is, as soon as you start editing the new buffer `fileA.h`, Vim will abort the `:g` command, because, ... well you moved away from the buffer ‍♂️

So I would instead try to use the following: Open all matched files in a new tabpage and immediately move back to the original tabpage.

Something like this should do it:

```
:g/ +\d/exe ":norm \<c-w>gF"|norm gT
```

This does the following:

- find each line matching `+\d` and
- execute [`<CTRL-W>gF`](https://vimhelp.org/windows.txt.html#CTRL-W_gF) on the match, which is basically the same as `gF` except that it will open the file in a new buffer (and leave the current window and tab alone)
- and immediately jump back to the previous tabpage [`gT`](https://vimhelp.org/tabpage.txt.html#gT) to allow the `:g` command to continue.

Comment: Thanks. It works. But I don't want to use tabs. Shouldn't it work for buffers instead of tabs like this? `:g/ +\d/exe ":norm gF"|norm \<C-^>` (It doesn't. I don't know why.)

Comment: I just noticed that with this tab approach files are opened in reverse order :-(

Comment: I guess you want `:g/ +\d/exe ":norm gF"|exe ":norm \<C-^>"` then.

Comment: Awesome! This is exactly what I need. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a simple way to do that.

It can be done with a recording:

```
" record macro
qq          " start recording in register q
/+\d<CR>    " search for line number
b           " move cursor back one word to the filename
<C-w>gF     " open file at line in new tab page
q           " stop recording

" playback macro from register q as many times as needed
23@q        " 23 times for 23 remaining filenames
```

If you need it often, it might be wise to invest in a bit of scripting.

Comment: Thanks. (Actually I don't want to open files in a tab. But I can simply skip `<C-w>`.) This is strange: I executed the macro only once and both files were opened!

Answer (score 0):

A different way to approach this would be to populate the Quickfix list

```
:setlocal efm=%f\ +%l
:cbuffer
```

Now you should be on the first file location. You can use `:cnext`/`:cprev` to go through the list. Use `:copen` to see your list. Can even use `:cdo`/`:cfdo` if you want to execute a command on each location/file

One side effect is this does set the local `'errorformat'` setting.

Another low-tech way to do something similar is to set an uppercase mark, e.g. `mM`. Then `gf` to the file you want to go. When you are done return with `'M`

For more help see:

```
:h 'efm'
:h :cbuffer
:h :cn
:h :cope
:h m
```